# I can't refer to textBox checkBox etc

Tags: c#, reference

I am trying to refer to object from .cshtml file in .cs file but it doesn't work. It says the name doesn't exist.

**cshtml.cs file**

```
public class ParticipateModel : PageModel
    {

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Your application description page.";
                   }

        protected void sendDataToKonkurs(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = txtName.Text;

        }
```

**cshtml file**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" maxlength="20" formmethod="post" style="margin-bottom:20px">
```

Answer (score 0):

this example might help you front end code:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DefaultControls.aspx.cs" 
  Inherits="ControlsMix.DefaultControls" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CbClientName" runat="server" Width="300px">

        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</form>
```

backend c# code which loads the values into combo box

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CbClientName.Items.Add("John");
        CbClientName.Items.Add("Smith");
        CbClientName.Items.Add("Dylan");
        CbClientName.Items.Add("Ben");
    }
```

just ensure your id="whatevername" is the same in the backend of the code this binds the control in asp.net